# Google Map Navigation and Direction in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I wan to use google map navigation and direction functionality in my iPhone App.
Is there any sample app or documents which should I refer? Is this paid functionality?

Thanks,

Comment: Google's turn-by-turn direction functionality is only available on Android.

Comment: U mean to say it is not possible in iPhone?

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want to do. If you want it to look and function like Android's turn-by-turn functionality, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Google Maps the google provides a really good API.

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)

For the direction it depends what you need. For the direction you head up to you can use the compass. If you want to track the direction of your movement you can do that with GPS.

If you don't want to use google maps you can use 
the [Route Me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/) example (Open source iPhone-native slippy map), which already includes functions like tracking and many more.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find directions between two GPS coordinates or two addresses, you can use Google Directions API.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

You can have it read out xml or JSON and from there, parse it and do with it whatever you want.